# Insert a raw image in my Website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I've got a raw image : either a `Bitmap` object, or a `byte[]`. How may I include it in my website (in an .cshtml file), without saving it on my computer ?

I'm using c#, and the project follow the MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image in your html as a base64 string. However, You do need to know the mime-type of the image as well because that has to be prefixed to the string.

For example:

```
<img src="data:@mime;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes))" />
```

As a rendered example, this will show a dot:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```